# How to get 2 results from 3 tables with 1 mysql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like this

```
soft_id   soft_name
1         Office

pu_id   soft_id   pu_quantity
1       1         10
2       1         20
3       1         30

own_id   soft_id   owner
1        1         Peter
2        1         Tommy
3        1         David
```

How can I have a result like this in one single mysql query

```
soft_id   soft_name   sum(pu_quantity)   count(owner)
1         Office      60                 3
```

Comment: I tried this and get same result, but don't know mine or Christian Mark's is better 
SELECT a.soft_id, a.soft_name, count(c.owner) AS number FROM tracking, (SELECT a.soft_id, a.soft_name, sum(b.pu_quantity) AS total FROM a, b WHERE a.soft_id =b.soft_id)
AS table_test WHERE c.soft_id = table_test.soft_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.soft_id,
  a.soft_name,
  b.p_cnt AS quantity,
  c.o_cnt AS owner_count
FROM soft a
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT soft_id, SUM(pu_quantity) AS p_cnt FROM product GROUP BY soft_id
  ) b
ON a.soft_id = b.soft_id
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT soft_id, COUNT(*) AS o_cnt FROM owner GROUP BY soft_id
  ) c
ON b.soft_id = c.soft_id
GROUP BY a.soft_id,
  a.soft_name
```

---

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abbe3/8)

Note: assuming that the table names are soft, product and owner respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT S.soft_id,S.soft_name,P.sum(pu_quantity),O.count(owner)
FROM Soft S INNER JOIN Product P ON S.soft_id = P.soft_id
Inner JOIN Owner O = P.soft_id = O.soft_id
Group By S.soft_id,P.soft_id,O.soft_id,S.soft_name
```